# how to convert column values to str when reading multi-sheet xlsx using pd.read_excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have a muti-sheet `xlsx` file which I want to process selected pages and finally save them as `CSV`.

This is a snapshot of a few raws from one page:

[image]

I use this code to load all pages and process each one-by-one:

```
def load_raw_excel_file(file_full_name):

    df = pd.read_excel(file_full_name, sheet_name=None, engine="openpyxl", header=0)
    sheets_name = list(df.keys())

    return df, sheets_name
```

The output of the code (from the same page) looks like this:

```
dfs, shs =  load_raw_excel_file("myexelfile.xlsx")
dfs['myselectedsheetname']
```

[image]

As you can see, some values from the `Contract` column have changed to date, but I don't want any changes.
I've tried using `convertors` and `dtype` in `pd.read_excel`, but it didn't work:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_full_name, sheet_name=None, engine="openpyxl", header=0, dtype=str)
```

or

```
df = pd.read_excel("myexelfile.xlsx", sheet_name='selectedsheetname', header=0, converters={'Contract':str})
```

any idea?

**Update**

I found a workaround but not a good solution:

```
def convert_str_date(x):
    
    try:
        y = x.strftime("%b-%y")
        return y
    except:
        return x


df.Contract.apply(lambda x : convert_str_date(x))
```

Also, see @Simon answer

Answer (score 1):

the excel set those values to datetime format. maybe you can postprocess with the dataframe,

```
nKCol = df['Contract']                                            
oKCol = df['Contract'].copy()

# update cell to %b-%y string format; Nan if error                            
nKCol = pd.to_datetime(nKCol, errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%b-%y')

# update the column
df['Contract'] = nKCol   
  
# fill Nan with original column                                       
df['Contract'] = df['Contract'].fillna(oKCol)
```

Comment: yep, seems there's no other way. I solved it a a similar way: 
```def convert_str_date(x):
    
    try:
        y = x.strftime("%b-%y")
        return y
    except:
        return x


df.Contract.apply(lambda x : convert_str_date(x))
```